# sorted (very) big neted list/dict in python

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have a very tricky problem in python 2.7 with a list and nested dict.

I have a list like this one:

```
    [
"modeA", 
{
    "alpha": {
        "mainFF": {
            "blocType": "f000", 
            "baseAddress": "]254:0x0]" 

        }
    }
}, 
"modeA", 
{
    "alpha": {
        "sideM": {
            "blocType": "smmm", 
            "baseAddress": "]0x100:0x0]" 

        }, 
        "observer_main_ErrorLogger_0": {
            "blocType": "assa", 
            "baseAddress": "]0x180:0x100]" 

        }
    }
}, 
"modeA", 
{
    "beta": {
        "mainFF": {
            "blocType": "Firewall", 
            "baseAddress": "]0x1000:0x0]" 

        }
    }
}, 
"modeB", 
{
    "beta": {
        "sideM": {
            "blocType": "SidebandManager", 
            "baseAddress": "]0x100:0x0]" 

        }, 
        "observer_main_ErrorLogger_0": {
            "blocType": "ErrorLogger_0", 
            "baseAddress": "]0x180:0x100]"

        }
    }
}

]
```

It's actually in JSON format for more visibility but before to convert it to JSON its a list with multiple dictionaries and also just some strings like `modeA` and `modeB`

I would like to sort this (BIG!) list by `mode`.
And also convert this list to a 100% dict => so `modeA` and `modeB` will become a key in the new dict
Output desried:

```
{
"modeA":{
    "alpha": {
        "mainFF": {
            "blocType": "f000", 
            "baseAddress": "]254:0x0]" 

        },
        "sideM": {
            "blocType": "smmm", 
            "baseAddress": "]0x100:0x0]" 

        }, 
        "observer_main_ErrorLogger_0": {
            "blocType": "assa", 
            "baseAddress": "]0x180:0x100]" 

        }
    },

    "beta": {
        "mainFF": {
            "blocType": "Firewall", 
            "baseAddress": "]0x1000:0x0]" 

        }
    }
},

"modeB":{
    "beta": {
        "sideM": {
            "blocType": "SidebandManager", 
            "baseAddress": "]0x100:0x0]" 

        }, 
        "observer_main_ErrorLogger_0": {
            "blocType": "ErrorLogger_0", 
            "baseAddress": "]0x180:0x100]" 

        }
    }
}

}
```

My strategy was to split the original list into the even elements of the list(i.e: mode type) to another sub-list and then iterate and try to sort the nested dict.

If someone can help me I will very much appreciate it !!

Comment: That's not sorting, that's grouping. Look at [itertools.groopby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered. They cant be sorted unless you are using an `OrderedDict` or you rely on the insertion order of Python3.6+ dictionaries.

Comment: How big is it? What have you done to implement a solution? Did it run too slow?